# Adding media (jpg, mp3, mp4) to a web page from an outside source

Tags: html, css, webserver, external, media

I have a webserver running on a storage server and I am looking to access some of the media on it (ie. use an image from the nas as a background on the page). I have tried this with no luck:

```
background-image:url("file://SERVER01/Media/Family/5102.jpg");
```

as well as other variations, such as:

```
background-image:url("file:///SERVER01/Media/Family/5102.jpg");
background-image:url("file://../Media/Family/5102.jpg");
background-image:url("file:///../Media/Family/5102.jpg");
```

When I access the page from my laptop, the background image is broken, but if I look at the source and copy the link (Only the ones with SERVER01 in them) directly in, the image pops up fine.

What is the best way of troubleshooting this? What is the safest way of using these images without compromising the security of my server?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access files on your remote server you will need to use a public facing hostname & URI, you cannot use local file paths outside of the doc root because it will not be visible to the client / website user.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should clarify. The web server is also on `SERVER01` in the directory `SERVER01\web\ `. So, is there any possible way to make the stuff in `SERVER01\Media\ ` accessible?

Comment: You either need to mount the directory structure within a webroot, or set up a webserver on SERVER01 and give it a public hostname.

Comment: I apologize, but I am quite new to anything web related. I don't want to make SERVER01 openly available, which I believe will happen if I change the webserver to SERVER01 instead of SERVER01\web. Is there any way to just grab the files I need? I am trying to avoid vulnerabilities.

Comment: In that case the best thing to do is copy the asset / image from the NAS Into the webroot and use it then. It's a little more work, but it keeps the rest of the data on SERVER01 secure.

Comment: This means you would have the image in the same directory as the HTML / JS file that is using it and your code would look like:    ```background-image:url("5102.jpg");```